# getSharedPreferences using R.something?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

With these lines:

```
String app_name = "@string/app_name";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(app_name, 0);
```

I get an `IllegalArgumentException`:

> File @string/app_name.xml contains a path separator

If I do this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyAppName", 0);
```

It works fine but how do I use this without hard-coding the app name?
I can't use R.string.app_name because that is an int.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
String app_name = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(app_name, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can't get the Sting From `strings.xml` like this `String app_name = "@string/app_name";` in your `java Code`

To get String From `strings.xml` to `java Code`

Use `getResources().getString(R.string.yourStringName);`

**SO Change your Code to**

```
String app_name = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
```